# How is the domain and ranges of two function related to the domain and range of the composite function?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

> The functions $f$ and $g$ have domains $(0,\infty)$ and $(2,\infty)$ respectively and are defined by
>
> $$f(x)=x^2-1$$
>
> $$g(x)=2x-1$$
>
> Find the domain and range of $fg(x)$

The question for this specific problem was find the domain and range for $fg(x)$, however i keep getting the wrong answer the way i look at it is that the domain of $g(x)$ leads to values of $(3,\infty)$ however the $f(x)$ function can only take values between $(0,\infty)$ therefore it need to make $g(x)=0$ then from there find the values for which it can take in which case i get the domain for the composite function to be $(0.5,\infty)$ however the text book states that the answer is  $(2, ∞)$
any help is much appreciated
[question Pt.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDbBt.png)
[question Pt.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDbBt.png)

Comment: Welcome to SE Mathematics, Vincenzo! Could you please reword your question to avoid linking to a photo online? It is more helpful to see it all on here. If you are unsure about mathematical typesetting, the community should be able to help, and there are tips at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $f\circ g$ is the set on which it is defined, and it is defined for all $x>2$. Suppose that $x>2$. Then $x$ is in the domain of $g$, so $g(x)$ is defined. Moreover, as you said, $g(x)>3$, so in particular $g(x)>0$. Thus, $g(x)$ is in the domain of $f$, and $f(g(x))$ is therefore defined. The fact that some elements of the domain of $f$ aren’t in the range of $g$ is irrelevant.

To complete the argument, we note that if $x\le 2$, then $g(x)$ isn’t even defined, so $f(g(x))$ certainly isn’t defined. Thus, $x$ is in the domain of $f\circ g$ if and only if $x>2$.